# Android 4.3 WebViewClient shouldOverrideUrlLoading weird behaviour

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using WebView and try to intercept some special Url's in order to respond to events in the WebView using the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method.
for each of those special Url I return true in that method. 
It works fine in android 5 and android 4.4 but when i tried it on android 4.3 the WebView is trying to load those special urls

for now I used onPageStarted and for each of those Url's I just go to the previous Url. but it doesn't seem to me like a real solution.

why doesn't shouldOverrideUrlLoading intercept those Url's?

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();

    if (host.equals(SPECIAL_URL_PREFIX)){
        // Do something
        return true; // Intercept the Url
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: user1746700@: Did you try logging (via `android.util.Log`) the urls and hosts that you are getting? Is `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` getting called at all on 4.3 for you?

Comment: when I debbuged it I entered shouldOverrideUrlLoading and returned true but still tried to load the url

Comment: @user1746700 Did you solve this issue? Im running into the same thing atm.

Comment: I tried this method in order to handle iOS and Android the same in the JS. Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. I had to use java script interface in Android.